# Hay, sorry if it looks like I was taking over the site

Tags: discussion

I was just updating references to the Audio EQ Cookbook to the [W3 page](https://www.w3.org/TR/audio-eq-cookbook/), which, I think, is the final resting place for it.

Answer (score 1):

Great that it's in the W3 page! Sounds good, thanks for letting us know.